# DataTable and big SqlDecimal

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, decimal, sqlbulkcopy

I just found out that when you use `DataTable` and `SqlBulkCopy` in an attempt to load a SQL Server table, you can't use big decimal values.

`DataTable` only supports the .NET `decimal` type. .NET `decimal` is smaller than SQL Server `decimal`, so when you exceed the .NET range, you get an exception.

I prepared a `DataTable` that contains data rows with `SqlDecimal` columns and tried to bulk-load it.

```
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
```

But I get this error:

> InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlDecimal to a Decimal.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Update: After David's answer I double-checked the error. It turns out that it is not `decimal` but `smallmoney` column that caused this issue. An attempt to put SqlDecimal into `smallmoney` raises an error. It is very easy to avoid, for `smallmoney` and `money` columns .NET `decimal` is big enough.

Comment: Do you really need a precision of 38 ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately we store data in that precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't repro that.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

using var con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=tempdb;integrated security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true");
con.Open();

var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "drop table if exists foo; create table foo(id int, d decimal(38,2))";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("d", typeof(SqlDecimal));

var d = SqlDecimal.Parse("123456789012345678901234567890123456.78");
dt.Rows.Add(1, d);


var bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
bc.DestinationTableName = "foo";
bc.WriteToServer(dt);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for confusion, David. It is a smallmoney column that raises this exception. To reproduce replace 'foo(id int, d smallmoney)', SqlDecimal.Parse("214748.3647") in your code. There is no any need to use SqlDecimal for money, so this is not an error. Big decimals work fine.